# If two primal problems with different primal variables have the same dual problem, what can we say about the optimal points of those primal problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If two primal problems with different primal variables have the same dual problem, what can we say about the optimal points of those primal problems? Specifically,

1. Do these problems share global/local optima?
2. Can these two primal problems be called equivalent?

We also assume that, one of the primal problems have a non-zero duality gap and there is no assumption on the convexity of these problems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think you can say anything about the primal problems (other than dual provides a bound for primal, i.e., weak duality) unless it is known that strong duality holds for both primal problems with their dual.